# jQuery menu with sliding highlighter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, slide

I would like to do something like this: http://dreamapp.de/sites/portfolio/

At the moment this is done with an additional list item which has `position: absolute`. So I simply move the list item to the same place as the active list item. But this solution will only work if the content is not dynamically centered. So beside it's an ugly but working, solution, there must be a better one, right?

I thought that I've seen similar things on other website, but I couldn't find anything like this. So how could I do this better?

HTML:

```
    <nav id="menu2" class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="marker"></li>
            <li class="nav1"><a href="javascript:;">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav2"><a href="javascript:;">HTML/CSS</a></li>
            <li class="nav3"><a href="javascript:;">JavaScript</a></li>
            <li class="nav4"><a href="javascript:;">Resources</a></li>
            <li class="nav5"><a href="javascript:;">Tutorials</a></li>
            <li class="nav6"><a href="javascript:;">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".nav1 a").click(function() {
    $(".marker").stop().animate({left:'8px'},200, function() {
        $(".marker").stop().animate({display:'show'}, 200);
    });
});
$(".nav2 a").click(function() {
    $(".marker").stop().animate({'left':'118px'},200, function() {
        $(".marker").stop().animate({display:'show'}, 200);
    });
});
.
.
.
```

CSS:

```
.menu ul li.marker {
   width: 110px;
   height: 45px;
   background-color: #42ff2e;
   display:none;
   position: absolute;
}

.menu { 
    width: 660px;
    height: 45px;
    display: block;
}
.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.menu ul li {
    float: left; 
    overflow: hidden;       
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 45px;
}
.menu ul li a { 
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 110px;
    height: 45px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you could use this for fixed navigation item width http://jsfiddle.net/UqUBr/
(for variable navigation item width - http://jsfiddle.net/bdmjC/)

JS:

```
var navigation = $('nav'),
    items = navigation.find('.item'),
    itemWidth = 110

$(".item a").click(function() {
    var item = $(this).parent()

    $(".marker").stop().animate({left:items.index(item)*itemWidth},200, function() {
        $(".marker").stop().animate({display:'show'}, 200);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<nav id="menu2" class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="marker"></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="javascript:;">Home</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="javascript:;">HTML/CSS</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="javascript:;">JavaScript</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="javascript:;">Resources</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="javascript:;">Tutorials</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="javascript:;">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav#menu2 {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 660px;
  position: relative;
}
```